# Getting errorMessage while starting Appium on IntelliJ

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.14.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
      <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
```

On Baseclass,

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    public void appiumStart(){
            service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("//usr//local//lib//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js")).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4724).build();
            service.start();
    }
```

on the below line I'm getting nullPointerException:

```
service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(newFile("//usr//local//lib//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js")).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4724).build();
```

**Versions:**

- Appium: 2.1.3
- node: v16.15.1
- npm: 8.11.0
- java: 1.8
- java-client: 8.5.1

I tried with different versions of appium and java-client, but couldn't resolve the issue [Having main.js file too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yWMm.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(newFile("//usr//local//lib//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js")).usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe")).withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4724).build();
```

use this if now working then add withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOCAL_TIMEZONE)